# I cant disable a textbox with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I am trying to disable/enable the txtPeriodTo control when the checkbox Change event occurs, but it does not seem to work. I ma using jquery 1.10.4 and both prop and attr method of disabling the textbox does not work.

```
<div id="dvWrapper" class="dvWrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tdtDescription">Role:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtRoleTitle" class="txtRoleTitle" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tdtDescription">Company Name:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtCompanyName" class="txtCompanyName" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tdtDescription">Company Description:</td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea id="txtCompanyDescription" class="txtCompanyDescription"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tdtDescription">Period From
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtPeriodFrom" class="txtPeriodFrom" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>On-Going:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chkOnGoing" class="chkOnGoing" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tdtDescription">Period To
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtPeriodTo" class="txtPeriodTo" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>


$('.chkOnGoing').change(function () {
    var txtPeriodTo = $('.txtPeriodTo');
    if (this.checked) {
        txtPeriodTo.prop('disbaled', true);
    } else {
        txtPeriodTo.prop('disbaled', false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `disbaled` with `disabled`.

```
$('.chkOnGoing').change(function () {
    var txtPeriodTo = $('.txtPeriodTo');
    if (this.checked) {
        txtPeriodTo.prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        txtPeriodTo.prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```